# How to get a custom Date Range in power automate desktop

Tags: excel, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am still new to Power Automate Desktop I am trying to automate generating a report from a website in
for this I need a date range formula
My start date is 1st of current month
and end date is Current Date

I figure out how to put end date its just "Get Current Date and Time"

but for start date when I create a variable I dont get any option to code in the variable for instance I created a new variable called Start Date

so what do I put inside that variable so i get the 1st of current month.

Really confused on how to achieve this |

Thank you

Comment: you are on the right track with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407152/after-running-a-custom-scirpt-in-power-automate-how-to-get-the-output-in-a-new-v).

Comment: Yes man Following that up thank you so much