# After Running a Custom Scirpt in Power Automate how to get the Output in a new Variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, power-automate-desktop

I am running a custom PowerShell Script in Power Automate desktop

this is the script

```
    # Get the 1st day of the current month
$now_date = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year -Format "dd-MMM-yy"

# Get the last day of the current month
$month_after = (Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1) -Format "dd-MMM-yy"

# Initialize variables for the previous month's 1st and last days
$prev_month_first = $null
$prev_month_last = $null

# Check if now_date and month_after are the same
if ($now_date -eq $month_after) {
    # Calculate the 1st day of the previous month
    $prev_month_first = (Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month -Year (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Year) -Format "dd-MMM-yy"

    # Calculate the last day of the previous month
    $prev_month_last = (Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year).AddDays(-1) -Format "dd-MMM-yy"
}

# Output the values
$now_date, $month_after, $prev_month_first, $prev_month_last
```

Now when I set a new variable in power automate desktop I cant get the output of my 4 variables here

I set a new variable name it to "Now_Date"
and in value I put %now_date%

The output that the script gives me is named as %PowershellOutput%

but the result is always empty I don’t mind getting the result in text format as well because I have to copy paste it somewhere

Please can someone help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Script produces errors and thus returns a blank.

Enable the `ScriptError` variable under the variables produced options.
[image: EnableVariableForError]

There are other errors in your script:
[image: errorList]

The script should be this:

```
# Get the 1st day of the current month
$now_date = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year -Format "dd-MMM-yy"

# Get the last day of the current month
$month_after = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).AddMonths(1).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year -Format "dd-MMM-yy"

# Initialize variables for the previous month's 1st and last days
$prev_month_first = $null
$prev_month_last = $null

# Check if now_date and month_after are the same
if ($now_date -eq $month_after) {
    # Calculate the 1st day of the previous month
    $prev_month_first = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year -Format "dd-MMM-yy"    
    #calculate last day of month
    $last_days_in_month = [DateTime]::DaysInMonth((Get-Date).Year, (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month)
    # Calculate the last day of the previous month
    $prev_month_last =  Date -Day $last_days_in_month -Month (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month -Year (Get-Date).Year -Format "dd-MMM-yy"
}
# Output the values
$now_date, $month_after, $prev_month_first, $prev_month_last
```

Get your script to run correctly in PowerShell, when I tested your script in *Windows PowerShell ISE* I got the same errors.

Once your script passes you will see the output in `%PowershellOutput%` this will be a multiline string, so you could use the *Split Text* action in power automate desktop to get a list, after which you can get the values according to the index in `TextList` variable.

*copy and then paste this text to a power automate desktop*

```
Text.SplitText.SplitWithDelimiter Text: PowershellOutput CustomDelimiter: $'''\\n''' IsRegEx: True Result=> TextList
```

You should get something like this
[image: splittextaction]

Get the values using the index position, so `%TextList[1]%` will give you the string calculated by `$month_after`.

If you wanted to return everything as a single string then you can write your last line something like

`Write-Host "$($now_date), $($month_after) ...etc"`

Comment: Hey man thank you so much for this I dont want to return it as a string because I am inputting the date in a text field in web 
when i try to input it as a text i am getting an error in power automate saying 
"Argument 'BrowserInstance' must be 'Web browser instance"
Also it would be really helpful if you could tell me the other things which are wrong with my Code
I dont know if its related but i will try that

Comment: When I tried your script above in PowerShell (PS), I got a list of error messages, so you will have to make sure your script works perfectly in PS. If you used PS on one machine to get your script and Power Automate Desktop (PAD) is on another, make sure the versions of PS match on both machines. Your browser message might indicate that you have not loaded the browser, I can't really say, but it won't be anything to do with the PS script.

Comment: Wow this is beyond what I expected Thanks CobyC
So I will tell you what I am doing if it helps
I am trying to automate report generation from a website called Smart Office it runs on an IP 
I have a huge if condition that if now_date <> current_date input now_date and in the next field month_after
but if it is input prev_month_first in the first field and prev_month_last in the next field 

so i want these 4 variable to be independent if am not wrong
I want the answer in a single 'Set Variable'
so i can input the datetime in the field

Comment: Yes, the value in %PowershellOutput% variable is just text, to make it 'easier' to get the values independently you create a List variable using the Split text action. You could also use `Write-Host "$($now_date), $($month_after), $($prev_month_first), $($prev_month_last)"` and then split it by the comma. Then when using something like the Populate text field action, you can use `%TextList[0]%` where you need to enter the value of *now_date* and `%TextList[1]%` will have the value of *month_after* etc..

Comment: Thats amazing thank youuu

Comment: I am back here again,
My result is coming as 
01-Nov-23
01-Dec-23

whereas i want 01-Nov-23
30-Nov-23

Its not giving me the date of the last date of the month

Comment: it is pretty much the same as what is in the if statement for previous month, but without the `.AddMonth(-1)` bit.